# Is "went off in search of her hedgehog" a VP, and can it be broken down further?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, linguistics, verb-phrases

I am new to linguistics and am currently learning how to figure out phrase markers for sentences.
I am unsure about this sentence:

She went off in search for her hedgehog.

I know that "she" is a noun phrase, but I am unsure about the VP.

Is the VP "went off in search for her hedgehog"?

And does that split again into the three phrases: went off, in search and for her hedgehog?

Does it look like this?

[image]

Comment: There may be some disagreement over what to do with **off**.

Comment: What research have you done on this topic so far?

Comment: @alphabet: OP offers a splitting up of the sentence. The research is implicit.  Are you expecting a quotation from a textbook about constituents or something?

Comment: There is an awkwardness with "in search for" where the usual way of expressing this is "in search **of** *something*". I suppose *of* is still a preposition and the grammar doesn't change. The juxtaposition of "off in" is not particularly idiomatic either.

Comment: No, I just need to figure out which phrases the sentence consists of, in order to be able to examine their components in turn. I have figured out - but I am not sure, if that's right - NP: she
VP = Verb (went) and Particle (off) + PP: Preposition (in) and NP (search) + PP: Preposition (for) and NP (determiner her and noun hedgehog)

Comment: I don't think it's grammatical and therefore it's unparseable. Where does it come from? Why do you think it's valid?

Comment: @Stuart F What do you mean by not grammatical? The sentence itself or the phrase structure I wrote down?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: What's wrong with "off in"? Seems perfectly idiomatic to me! (But I agree it should be "in search *of*".)

Comment: @psmears I agree with you, but that is the sentence, that was given (:

Comment: I've corrected the sentence; the basic question is unaffected, and the question is now valid (the example doesn't contain what most would consider an error). // This question should not be closed; LPH's answer includes important and clarifying information on the differing ways different linguists use / have used the important term 'verb phrase'.

Comment: Yes it is a verb phrase, and yes it can be broken down further.

Answer (score 2):

In *traditional grammar* the term "verb phrase" refers strictly to verbal forms. Here are verb phrases of all possible lengths for "to sink" (finite verb forms, at most four auxiliaries).

- The ship *sank/was sinking/has been sunk/must have been sinking/may have been being sunk (rare)* (*example from CoGEL*)

In a sentence such as "She … hedgehog.", the usual term for "went off in search of her hedgehog" is "*predicate*".

In linguistics the term "verb phrase" takes on a new signification.

> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_phrase) In linguistics, a verb phrase (VP) is a syntactic unit composed of a verb and its [arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)) except the subject of an independent clause or coordinate clause. Thus, in the sentence *A fat man quickly put the money into the box*, the words *quickly put the money into the box* constitute a verb phrase; it consists of the verb *put* and its arguments, but not the subject *a fat man*. A verb phrase is similar to what is considered a predicate in traditional grammars.

- *in search of her hedgehog*: prepositional phrase
- *of the hedgehog*:  (embedded) prepositional phrase

Comment: Is my assumption correct:
S = 
NP: she 
VP = Verb (went) and Particle (off) + PP: Preposition (in) and NP (search) + PP: Preposition (for) and NP (determiner her and noun hedgehog)

Comment: @lingheng The NP "she" is the subject. "Went off" is a phrasal verb, which means that both the verb form "go" and the adverb "off" constitute a verb,  "Went off" is the VP (traditional grammar), also called the main verb. Embeddings are not shown by means of plus signs. (1/2)

Comment: @lingheng  You have two PP and two NP. PP: in (prep.)  search (noun) [for (prep.)  her (det.)  hedgehog (noun)], for (prep.)  her (det.)  hedgehog (noun) — NP: search (noun)  for (prep.)  her (det.)  hedgehog (noun), her (det.)  hedgehog (noun). VP (linguistics): went off (main verb) <PP: in (prep.)  search (noun)  <PP: [for (prep.)  her (det.)  hedgehog (noun)]>>. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you very much. I know that embeddings aren't shown by plus signs, I only did it this way first, to roughly divide it up for me because in the end I have to draw a tree diagram.

Comment: In search **of** her hedgehog. You failed to correct the mistake. :)

Comment: *Here are all the possible types of verb phrases for "to sink" (finite vetb forms)* Why not "has sunk", "does sink", "must sink", etc.?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That was an error; I corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Lambie: no, the sentence is "She went off in search for her hedgehog."

Comment: @lingheng If that is what you found somewhere, it is incorrect and needs correcting as Lambie says. 'She went off in search for her hedgehog' is non-standard. 'Girl goes off in search for hedgehog' is telegraphese, not acceptable in normal registers, but 'She went off in search for her hedgehog' looks more like something a non-native speaker might produce. 'She went off to search for ...' or even 'she went off in a search for ...', yes ... but 'in search of' is a fixed phrase found in many dictionaries, while 'in search for' isn't.

Comment: 'In _modern treatments of_ linguistics, ...'. // And I've corrected the fixed phrase in the question. //// A good and necessary explanation of the conflicting definitions of 'verb phrase'. One often meets one definition in a thread not explaining that it's not the only one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are a good many instances of "in search for" on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20search%20for%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), although a non-negligible part of those could to be due to non-native writers.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I asked and received this information: The sentence is from "Lewis Carroll's Alice's Adventures in Wonderland (Chapters Pig and
Pepper and The Queen's Croquet-Ground), with some sentences taken slightly shortened.

Comment: @lingheng Nope, the question says OF and not FOR.

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I have to apologize. Yes, at the top the sentence said "in search of", but at the bottom of my question it said "in search for", which is the correct form in the sentence, so: She went off in search for her hedgehog.

Comment: @lingheng In *Alice in Wonderland* the sentence is "So she went in search of her hedgehog.";  https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/11/pg11.txt

Comment: @lingheng This question has a good answer and is worth keeping, but if you insist on using non-standard English, it might sadly be closed. Check LPH's link for the actual correct form in common use. Or look at Google stats comparing hits for "She went off in search for her hedgehog" vs those for "She went off in search of her hedgehog". I've edited to the idiomatic version once.

Comment: @LPH @ Edwin Ashworth 
Okay, sorry, but the sentence appears in different forms. Yes, in the text from your link it shows up as you wrote it. On this page (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19033/19033-h/19033-h.htm), however, it appears like this: "So she went off in search of her hedgehog."

I understand what you are saying about the correct usage, but I was assigned the phrase "She went off in search for her hedgehog." and that's why I am unsure, because I am not allowed to change any of the words in this phrase and yet I am supposed to create a phrase marker.

Comment: So it's not really about discussing whether the "went off" or the "in search for" is correct, but, rather, my question regarding the phrases and how they are ultimately related in the sentence, which is why I've also shown the tree diagram.

Comment: @lingheng That is clear, it's not the point of your question; however,  the errors that are found in the written text of a question, whatever its origin, should be corrected; that should be done even before examining the question, as soon as they are detected. You can swap the prepositions as concerns your assignment, while still mentioning to your teachers that the preposition is not that used in the book, nor the usual one in the context of "search" being preceded by "in".